# Show both ctime and atime in ls output

Tags: bash, ls

Can I get both ctime and atime in ls output? Seems I can only pass one `--time=ctime` or `--time=atime` argument (the second is ignored). Is there any other way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could run `stat -c '%x %z' filename.txt`

Comment: Just note that `stat -c '%w %x %y %z' filename.txt` gives you creation, access, data modification, status change. In human-readable format.

Comment: On a Mac this would look more like `stat -f "%c %a %N" filename.txt` (change it to `%Sc %Sa` for human readable).

Answer (score 20):

If you are only parsing values out of `ls`, you can use `stat` instead:

```
# stat -c %x,%z,%n *
2011-01-11 06:09:04.000000000 -0500,2011-01-11 02:43:52.000000000 -0500,sqlupdate.sh
2011-01-11 06:09:04.000000000 -0500,2011-01-12 02:43:55.000000000 -0500,file.tar.gz
2011-01-11 06:09:04.000000000 -0500,2011-01-11 02:43:52.000000000 -0500,mysql_password.txt
2011-01-17 02:43:49.000000000 -0500,2011-01-12 13:40:48.000000000 -0500,public_html
```

Where:

```
 %x     Time of last access
 %z     Time of last change
 %n     Name of file
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the answers here. It is possible with ls to display any of access, modified and change time, but not more than one at a time. Because that is both really surprising, and very annoying.

Answer (score 6):

with `find`you get very close to what `ls -l`provides:

```
# find . -maxdepth 1 \
     -printf "%M %u %g %s\t%Ab %Ad %AH:%AM\t%Cb %Cd %CH:%CM\t%P\n"
```

you have access to ctime (%C), atime(%A) and modification time (%T). read `man find` to find more info.